# Remember state of cell after animation

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

Would much appreciate any advice on below.

I'm trying to make my table remember state after animation is completed. Below is my table, when I press button "Invite", animation removes buttons from cell. But during scroll down and back reusableCell draws buttons again.

I decided to use Array in order to remember, which cells were animated, but do not know how not to draw some elements of cell (buttons) during cell creation.

[image: MyTable]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a boolean variable called animationIsCalled and set it to false.

```
var animationIsCalled = [Bool](repeating: false, count: numberOfTableViewCells)

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
    if animationIsCalled{
        //Your code is here
    }
    animationIsCalled[indexPath.row] = false
}
```

I don't know if your method is an IBAction type or not, but if it is, you can't use indexPath.row. But try to use this boolean variable idea because I've used it before and it's a pretty useful strategy.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, thank you a lot for answer! After some experiments the following code worked:

```
//Create array to remember already animated cells
var sectionTwoSent = [String]()

//Once button tapped append user_id to array above
self.sectionTwoSent.append(self.sectionTwo[indexPath.row].user_id)

//During cell creation, make check and alpha = 0 to hide buttons
for item in sectionTwoSent {
 if contact.user_id == item {
    cell.inviteButton?.alpha = 0
    cell.removeButton?.alpha = 0
    cell.invitationDoneLabel?.alpha = 1
    break
    } else {
       cell.inviteButton?.alpha = 1
       cell.removeButton?.alpha = 1
       cell.invitationDoneLabel?.alpha = 0
    }
}
```